# can't find something in the source, but it's there

Tags: c#, facebook, web-scraping

So i have this code

```
        string source = "";
        try
        {
            string websiteName = "https://facebook.com/" + Membre.NomMembre;
            source = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(websiteName);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Copy stream to buffer.
                var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);

                // Decode byte array to UTF-8 string.
                source = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            }
        }
        if (source.Contains("og:title"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is taken.", Membre.NomMembre);
        }
```

if i go to to facebook.com/pokemon source , we can see it has `og:title`
but for some reason, i think it doesn't find it.

Comment: Do you get an error? What's in `source`? Use the debugger.

Comment: Are you sure it's returning the html page you expect? Many websites block unauthorized bots.

Comment: Try either debugging it with the Visual Studio debugger or save it to a file, to make sure it returns the same page source you expect. Be sure to keep Mitch's comment in mind as well.

Comment: Also, use an HTML parser.

Comment: I do not get any error from the debugguer

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem you are experiencing is that your `WebClient` is being rejected by FaceBook and the request is being redirected to a "Update your Browser Page".

If you want to see what the page looks like just copy the results of the `source` property and save it as a HTML page[image]

One way around this is by trying to spoof your WebClient browser agent by adding the user-agent header of a browser they support. I chose IE10 (as it was one I had handy). To add the header try.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)");
source = client.DownloadString(websiteName);
```

Now really you should be using the Facebook API's and this will probably get you barred from Facebook.

Comment: Why would it be better to use the facebook API's? and i've got it to work, thanks!

Comment: I am not 100% sure as I haven't read the usage policies of FaceBook but data mining via scraping may breach the terms. Anyway glad this worked for you. Cheers